# Which component calls xrandr when I connect/disconnect a display?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, xrandr

When I connect/disconnect a display from my notebook, the monitor layout is adapted automatically. Is there a way to turn that behavior off?

I have a nonstandard monitor setup, to which I am also applying panning and scaling. I want full manual control over the monitor setup. Also, when I try to configure manually my full tri-head setup, Gnome freezes -- I suspect that this is related to the hot-plug detection I want to turn off.

I've looked in `/etc/udev` but haven't found any rules. I also turned off the `xrandr` plugin by unchecking `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xrandr.active` in `dconf-editor` to no avail.

Comment: i believe it's due to dbus service, but i can't pin point which exactly. My guess would be the settings daemon dbus service, not the udev one, but that's as much as i can suggest off the top of my head

Comment: This might help: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg#Monitor_settings

Comment: @Serg: Thanks. Killing `gnome-settings-daemon` doesn't change matters.